# change mysql default engine to innodb

Tags: mysql

I am using mac and I installed mysql using homebrew.

```
brew install mysql
```

pretty standard installation.

```
mysql> show engines;
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine     | Support | Comment                                                    | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| MRG_MYISAM | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV        | YES     | CSV storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM     | DEFAULT | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance     | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB     | YES     | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| MEMORY     | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables  | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
```

I would like innodb to be the default storage engine. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 35):

Under `[mysqld]` section in your ini file, add:

```
default-storage-engine = innodb
```

It is usually `/etc/my.cnf`, but not sure about Mac.

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html):

> On Unix, Linux and Mac OS X, MySQL programs read startup options from the following files, in the specified order (top items are used first).
>
> ```
> File Name   Purpose
>
> /etc/my.cnf          Global options
> /etc/mysql/my.cnf    Global options (as of MySQL 5.1.15)
> SYSCONFDIR/my.cnf    Global options
> $MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf   Server-specific options
> defaults-extra-file  The file specified with --defaults-extra-file=path, if any
> ~/.my.cnf            User-specific options
> ```

The last one is never used by the daemon.

Comment: where is my ini file. How do I find where mysql will look for ini file.

Comment: got it . /etc/my.cnf worked because I am getting mysql: unknown variable 'default-storage-engine=innodb'

Comment: @Nadal: did you place it under `[mysqld]`?

Comment: In mac also its under /etc/my.cnf. Thanks it helped.

Comment: Also recommended is to use `innodb_file_per_table` so that each InnoDB table in your database gets its own `.ibd` file, rather than being stored in the monolithic `ibdata1` file.  See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15906/is-innodb-file-per-table-advisable as a starting reference.

Answer (score 0):

I can see from phpMyAdmin that MySQL has a database called `information_schema`, and it contains a table called `ENGINES`. Aside from the more global scenario of changing an ini file, wouldn't it be a simple solution to switch the table's `SUPPORT` fields for `MyISAM` and `InnoDB` (to 'YES' and 'DEFAULT' respectively)? I haven't done it myself, so proceed at your own risk ... and let me know how things turn out if you do.